# Pairs of J-holomorphic curves

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, symplectic-topology, pseudo-holomorphic-curves

Let $(M, \omega)$ be a symplectic 4-manifold and let $A$ and $B$ be symplectic submanifolds on M such that $A \cap B = p \in M$.Under what conditions can I find a $\omega$-compatible almost complex structure $J$ such that both $A$ and $B$ are J-holomorphic.

I understand that one would require certain necessary conditions like $[A] \cdot [B] = 1$ (In order to satisfy positivity on intersections in dimension 4) but is this condition sufficient?

Comment: You need to assume transverse intersection. Then this can be achieved for $\omega$-tame J (see for example Lemma 3.1 of McDuff’s *"Immersed spheres in symplectic 4-manifolds"*) but off the top of my head I’m not sure about subtleties for tame-to-compatible.

Comment: Thank you. I'll have a look at it.